# Convert the choice value by transforming the model to json format

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have that model.

```
ESTADO=(
    (0,'Desabilitado'),
    (1,'Habilitado')
)

class Cargo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Nombre',unique=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Descripcion', blank=True)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADO,default=1, verbose_name='Estado')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.nombre,self.get_estado_display())

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Cargo'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Cargos'
    ordering = ['-nombre']
```

I have this view:

```
def listar_cargos(request):
    object_list = Cargo.objects.all()
    json = serializers.serialize('json', object_list)
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

This returns me if you run it:

```
[
    {
        "fields": {
            "descripcion": "sdsds",
            "nombre": "dsds",
            "estado": 1
        },
        "model": "inventario.cargo",
        "pk": 4
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "descripcion": "Limpia",
            "nombre": "Conserje",
            "estado": 1
        },
         "model": "inventario.cargo",
        "pk": 2
    }
]
```

As I return to me? been converted to the value of choise. that is to say 
    {
        "descripcion": "sdsds",
        "nombre": "dsds",
        "estado": "Activo"
    }

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: object_list = Cargo.objects.all ()

Comment: I wish to pass JSON to state the value 1 is converted to "Active" with the choice

Comment: instead of [{"fields": {"descripcion": "sdsds", "nombre": "dsds", "estado": 1}]

I want to get to become the json

 [{"fields": {"descripcion": "sdsds", "nombre": "dsds", "estado": "Activo"}]

Comment: You could just write your own json method to serialize the object and call that.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Cargo(models.Model): 
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Nombre',unique=True) 
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Descripcion', blank=True) 
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADO,default=1, verbose_name='Estado')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.nombre,self.get_estado_display())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cargo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cargos'
        ordering = ['-nombre']

    @property
    def get_estado(self):
        return self.get_estado_display()
```

and then use model_obj.get_estado rather than model_obj.estado in your serializer definition.

you might have to use Django Rest Framework to do this successfully. If so see this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954424/331974