# serialize return choices value django representation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models.py like this:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  roles = (
        (u'1', u'task1'),
        (u'2', u'task2'),
    )
  role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=roles, default='1')
```

Then I have serializers.py looking like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = '__all__'
```

My viewset looks like this:

```
class Tasks(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tasks.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

So what I want to do is; say when I make a POSt request; I want to return saved data for tasks roles; if a I save it as 1, instead of returning roles field as 1, I want to return task1. How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945327/django-rest-framework-with-choicefield

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework with ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945327/django-rest-framework-with-choicefield)

Answer (score 1):

You can override `to_representation()` method in `Serializer class` as below,

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return_dict = dict(super().to_representation(instance))

        if self.context.get('view').action == 'create' and return_dict:
            choice_dict = {k[0]: k[1] for k in instance.roles}
            return_dict['role'] = choice_dict[return_dict['role']]

        return return_dict
```

**Short Description**
Here `self.context.get('view').action == 'create'` will check whether the view's action is a `create` (simplym, a `POST` request or not) or not.
So the output response for a `create` operation be like this,

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "role": "task2"
}
```

**Why did I do a type casting to `dict`?**
`to_representaion()` method return a `OrderedDict()` which is **immutable** object.