# DRF serializer return translated choice field value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, translate, choicefield

i'm using django-modeltranslation to translate mo models in DRF

so i did all that says docs of django-modeltranslation and it work for model fields

but i cant get translated value of choicefield

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Product(models.Model):

PRODUCT_TYPES = (
    ('food', _('food')),
    ('wear', _('wear'))
)
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=512, blank=True)
product_type = models.CharField('Type', choices=PRODUCT_TYPES, blank=True, null=True, max_length=16, default='food')
```

fields like `product_name` and other are translated by django-modeltranslation and works

but i always get `food` in `product_type`

i run makemessages and compilemessages

```
msgid "food"
msgstr "еда"

msgid "wear"
msgstr "одежда"
```

calling get_product_type_display did not work

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    product_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('phone_number', 'name', 'total_bonus', 'card_number', 'id', 'count', 'date', 'product_type',
                  'category')

    def get_product_type(self, obj):
        return obj.get_product_type_display()
```

Comment: have you create and compile translation before?

Comment: yes i did makemessages and compilemessages

Comment: You need to call get_product_type_display() on Product instance. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: @monio update my question for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework with ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945327/django-rest-framework-with-choicefield)

Answer (score 3):

Your serializer using get_FIELDNAME_display() object method:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    product_type = serializers.CharField(source='get_product_type_display', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('phone_number', 'name', 'total_bonus', 'card_number', 'id', 'count', 'date', 'product_type', 'category')
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem. Need to use: `return _(obj.product_type)`

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    product_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('phone_number', 'name', 'total_bonus', 'card_number', 'id', 'count', 'date', 'product_type',
                  'category')

    def get_product_type(self, obj):
        return _(obj.product_type)
```

Comment: You can try my solution.