# Django Rest Framework read/write ModelSerializer with ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a few field in my model "OrderItem" that are ChoiceFields or Enums. I want to represent the label of the choice and doing it with `serializers.CharField(source='get_service_display')`. See also [Django Rest Framework with ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945327/django-rest-framework-with-choicefield).

That works fine, but creating objects is not working anymore with following error message `OrderItem() got an unexpected keyword argument 'get_service_display'`

Here is my model

```
class OrderItem(TimeStampedModel):
    class Categories(models.IntegerChoices):
        GRASS = (1, _('grass'))

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=Categories.choices)
```

and here my serializer

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    category = serializers.CharField(source='get_category_display')

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['id', 'unit_price', 'category']
        read_only_fields = ['unit_price']
```

how can I create a model like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from rest_framework import fields
from your_app_path.models import Categories

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = fields.ChoiceField(Categories.choices)
```

One other note.  I'm not familiar with sub-classing models just for choices.  I usually do it this way:

```
class OrderItem(TimeStampedModel):
    GRASS = 'grass'

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (1, _(GRASS)),
        )

order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

Comment: How have I missed `ChoiceField`!? Thanks for sharing