# Why does React Native receive attributes that are `models.TextChoices` from Django as a tuple converted to a string?

Tags: django, react-native

I have this text choices model

models.py

```
class PostType(models.TextChoices):
    DECLARE = 'DECLARE'
    UPDATE = 'UPDATE'
    SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'


class Post(models.Model):
    # ulid does ordered uuid creation
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=generate_ulid_as_uuid, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    join_goal = models.ForeignKey(JoinGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=PostType.choices,
        max_length=50,
    )
```

for some reason on the mobile front-end it's returning as:

React Native Code

```
console.log(response[0].type)
console.log(typeof(response[0].type))
```

Console

```
 LOG  ('UPDATE', 'Update')
 LOG  string
```

The above were produced by `console.log` the response and `console.log` `typeof` on the key in the response as well. This tells me that Django is sending it as a tuple of `('<type all caps>', '<type camel case>')` and then React Native is converting it to a string and printing is as such. Why is this happening? **What can I do on Django to ensure just `'Declare'`, `'UPDATE'` or `'SUCCESS'` is returned to the react native?**

view.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_initial_posts(request, count):
    serializer = full_post_data_serializer(Post.objects.order_by('-uuid')[:count])
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

helper.py

```
def full_post_data_serializer(post_query_set: QuerySet):
    query_set_annotated = post_query_set.annotate(
        creator_username=F('creator__username'),
        goal_description=F('join_goal__goal__description'),
        goal_uuid=F('join_goal__goal__uuid'),
        reply_count=Count('replypost', distinct=True),
        cheer_count=Count('cheerpost', distinct=True)
    )
    return FullPostDataSerializer(query_set_annotated, many=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class FullPostDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    goal_uuid = serializers.SlugField()
    creator_username = serializers.SlugField()
    reply_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    cheer_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    goal_description = serializers.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'body', 'join_goal', 'created', 'creator_username', 'goal_description', 'reply_count', 'cheer_count',
            'images', 'uuid', 'type', 'creator', 'videos', 'goal_uuid'
        )
```

Comment: it is not clear how does your API is returning the response back to user/client. Add that information - better the minimal, yet complete example

Comment: added view and models code

Comment: @JPG I think this is more a property of how TextChoice is handled than how my API is returning the response. As you can see I'm not modifying that attribute in anyway and I think it's standard for TextChoice to be in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954424/1935069

This is slightly dependent on which version of DRF and Django you are using. What I would do is to be explicit and modify the serializer to use a [serializers.SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) and get the display value for the choices field like so:

```
class FullPostDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... # your existing code goes here
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_type(instance):
        return instance.type.value

    ...
```

This should return the proper value in the serializer.

Another thing to note is that `type` is a reserved keyword in python. You *can* use it like this, but really should not, so I suggest a rename of the variable if possible