# Deserialize a Array Choice Field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an array of choice fields. I want the human-readable text as a response instead of just numbers.

How to deserialize an array choice field in Django Rest Frameworks?

Response

```
 "categories": [
        1,
        2
    ],
```

Expected Response

```
 "categories": [
        "Carpentry",
        "Interior"
    ],
```

```
class ChoiceArrayField(ArrayField):

    def formfield(self,**kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField,
            'choices': self.base_field.choices,
            
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)

        return super(ArrayField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Model.py

```
categories_choices = (
        (1,"Carpentry"),
        (2,"Interior"),
        (3,"Furniture"),
        (4,"Plumber"),
        (5,"Electrican"),
        (6,"Construction"),
        (7,"Painting"),
        (8,"Flooring"),
        (9,"Yard Settings")
    )

    categories =  ChoiceArrayField(
        base_field = models.CharField(max_length=32,choices=categories_choices, null=True,blank=True),
        default=list,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
```

Serializer.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    phone_number = serializers.IntegerField(source='phone.phonenum')
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='phone.id')
    
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('phone',)
        model = ProfileModel
```

Comment: Dup of [Django Rest Framework with ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945327/django-rest-framework-with-choicefield)?

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    phone_number = serializers.IntegerField(source='phone.phonenum')
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='phone.id')
    
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('phone',)
        model = ProfileModel

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        categories = instance.get_categories_display()
        response["categories"] = categories        

    return response
```