# Add field don't exist in model in fields at serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

how can i add field in serializer... This field is not in model no more details thank you

[image: The Serializer]

[image: A APIView]

ça me renvoie une erreur "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `etat_civil` on serializer `Serializer_Professeur_Assistant`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `DescPersonne_Prod` instance.
Original exception text was: 'DescPersonne_Prod' object has no attribute 'etat_civil'."

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can see your field name `etat_civil` is duplicated for both `ChoiceField` and `CharField`. Make sure you make two of them have different field name to avoid collision.

Second, the way that you creating `ChoiceField` is wrong. I don't know about the version of `djangorestframework` you are using, but if you are using version more than `3.6.3`, then you may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954424/13121145). In this case of your code, [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) could be the best option for showing your customizing data.